# How do I fix this VAAPI error with an Intel Card?

Tags: 12.10, drivers, intel-graphics, 13.04, vaapi

How do I fix the error shown below:

The output of `vainfo`:

```
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: User requested driver 'i965'
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
vainfo: intel_driver.c:58: intel_driver_init: Assertion `dri_state->driConnectedFlag == VA_DRI2 || dri_state->driConnectedFlag == VA_DRI1' failed.
```

Card information via `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
        Memory at fea00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        I/O ports at dc00 [size=8]
        Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at fe900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device a001
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Memory at fe880000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
```

Comment: You seemed to have tagged the question with 12.10 and 13.04; which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Hi.. I have tried both versions.. with the same problem...